# How to add a class within php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code that is working well to pull in the posts from one category onto a page in wordpress:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=28');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

What I want to be able to do is add a css class to both the Title and the Content. I know very little PHP but maybe this will explain what I am trying to do.

```
<?php
    query_posts('cat=28');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    <div class="title-class">the_title();</div>
    <div class="content-class">the_content();</div>
    endwhile;
    ?>
```

I know this is way off but hope that someone can help a lowly front end designer :)

Comment: Can you post the_title and the_content functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use like :

```
<?php
    query_posts('cat=28');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
    <div class="title-class"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
    <div class="content-class"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php
    endwhile;
?>
```

#### Or

```
<?php
    query_posts('cat=28');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    echo '<div class="title-class">'.the_title().'</div>';
    echo '<div class="content-class">'.the_content().'</div>';
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! the first option works perfectly. The second put the class in, but it didn't wrap the title/content.